# How to mock objects which return a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a mock of this object for unit testing purposes.

```
sqs.listQueues().promise()
      .then(...
```

Here's one of my attempts at mocking this and still getting the error `sqs.listQueues(...).promise is not a function`

```
const sqs = {
    listQueues: () => Promise.resolve(this),
    promise: () => Promise.resolve()
  }
```

How can i properly mock this object?

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `listQueues()` should not return a promise. Maybe this would work:

```
const sqs = {
  listQueues: () => ({
    promise: () => Promise.resolve()
  })
}
```

Comment: Very concise and simple to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly naive version that might get you going.

```js
const mockResolve = (val, delay = 0) => () => 
  new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(val), delay))

const mockReject = (err, delay = 0) => () => 
  new Promise((_, rej) => setTimeout(() => rej(err), delay))

const sqs = {
  listQueues: () => ({
    promise: mockResolve('foo')
  })
}


sqs.listQueues().promise().then(console.log)
```

There are probably many things wrong with this, but it's only meant as a first pass.

Comment: Ah i see. `listQueues()` is a function that does not return a promise.